# How to generate standard competition ranks (not dense) for my Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

What I have is a leaderboard sorted according from high to low scores. I would like to assign standard competition ranks (1224) formulaically. All 7 people who have the highest score (30) should be rank 1. Then all with second-highest score (20) should receive rank 8 (skipping the tied ranks 2-7).

[Standard competition ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Standard_competition_ranking_(%221224%22_ranking))

The picture below shows what I want (it should actually be rank 8 not 7, that's a typo but you get what I mean).

[image]

Here's the link to my sample (the ranks are done how I don't want them there!) [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F-j9zF9MaksdhkM1INzOF6yUO3xYJ8uxxZgZliYQrpA/edit#gid=0).

Comment: You can add a column with this formula `=ArrayFormula(ROW(A:A))` but the best is to have an additionnal factor to determine who is rank 1. (seniority maybe ? )

Comment: 1. I have added missing information; please check. Always **include sample data in your question**, because your sheet will probably disappear at some time  2. Your sample data seems incorrect: afrah_khan_11 etc should be 8th

Comment: It's weird, the linked sheet seems to already implement the solution that's asked for. Please add sample data and a few more words what exactly you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy since your scores are already ordered, otherwise you have to sort them first.

```
=COUNTIF(C$1:C7,">"&C8)+1
```

[image]